# Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)

Tags: react-native, native-base

Please, I need help, so I can't solve this issue with the posts I watched, it has become into a headache. This apear in AS

[There is not a lot information about Requiring unknown module "392". I'm a new developer in React Native](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZgTF.png)

Comment: Are you trying to develop on ios? Sometimes erasing all data and settings and restarting the emulator will fix this when I've gotten this issue.

Comment: No, I develop in android :/

Comment: Are all of your gradle dependencies properly linked? Do you have your environment variables all set up?

Comment: Yeah, I was updated to React Native 0.62 I installed @react-navigation, and then the issue apear, so i don't need to link